# How can I restructure this array to condense the data into a more usable format in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I will try to explain the data I'm working with first, then I'll explain what I hope to do with the data, then I'll explain what I've tried so far. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

---

### What I'm working with:

I have an array containing survey responses. The first two items are the two answers for the first question and `responses` contains the number of people who selected those answers. The last three items are the three answers for the other question we asked.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [survey_id] => 123456789
        [question_text] => Have you made any changes in how you use our product this year?
        [d_answer_text] => No
        [responses] => 92
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [survey_id] => 123456789
        [question_text] => Have you made any changes in how you use our product this year?
        [answer_text] => Yes
        [responses] => 30
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [survey_id] => 123456789
        [question_text] => How would you describe your interaction with our staff compared to prior years?
        [answer_text] => Less Positive
        [responses] => 14
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [survey_id] => 123456789
        [question_text] => How would you describe your interaction with our staff compared to prior years?
        [answer_text] => More Positive
        [responses] => 35
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [survey_id] => 123456789
        [question_text] => How would you describe your interaction with our staff compared to prior years?
        [answer_text] => No Change
        [responses] => 72
    )
```

)

---

### What I want to achieve:

I want to create an array where the `question_text` is used as the key (or I might grab the `question_id` and use it instead), use the `answer_text` as a key, with the `responses` as the value. It would look something like this:

```
Array
(
[Have you made any changes in how you use our product this year?] => Array
    (
        [No] => 92
        [Yes] => 30
    )

[How would you describe your interaction with our staff compared to prior years?] => Array
    (
        [Less Positive] => 14
        [More Positive] => 35
        [No Change] => 72
    )
```

)

---

### Here's what I've tried:

```
$response_array = array();
foreach($result_array as $value){
    //$responses_array['Our question'] = array('answer 1'=>responses,'answer 2'=>responses);
    $responses_array[$value['question_text']] = array($value['answer_text']=>$value['responses']);
}
```

This does not work because each loop will overwrite the value for `$responses_array[$question]`.  This makes sense to me and I understand why it won't work.

My next thought was to try using `array_merge()`.

```
$responses_array = array();
foreach($result as $value){
    $question_text = $value['question_text'];
    $answer_text = $value['answer_text'];
    $responses = $value['responses'];
    $responses_array[$question_text] = array_merge(array($responses_array[$question_text],$answer_text=>$responses));
}
```

I guess my logic was wrong because it looks like the array is nesting too much.

```
Array
(
    [Have you made any changes in how you use our product this year?] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [No] => 92
                )

            [Yes] => 30
        )
```

My problem with `array_merge` is that I don't have access to all answers for the question in each iteration of the foreach loop.

I want to design this in a way that allows it to scale up if we introduce more questions with different numbers of answers. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a *reduce* job

```
$response_array = array_reduce($result_array, function($carry, $item) {
  $carry[$item['question_text']][$item['answer_text']] = $item['responses'];
  return $carry;
}, []);
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/687264

Comment: Thanks! array_reduce is exactly what I needed. I had no idea that existed.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Remove condition (see @Phil comment)

I think you are looking for something like that :

```
$output = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $output[$array[$i]['question_text']] [$array[$i]['answer_text']]= $array[$i]['responses'];
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: PHP is fairly forgiving around array literals. You probably don't need to check and initialise the sub-array

Comment: Runs on average 33% faster than my answer. I still think you don't need the `isset` and `= []` parts :)

Comment: Did you know you don't even need to initialise `$output` ;-) https://eval.in/687280

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach than the answer posted, more in tune with what you'v already tried. Try This:

```
$responses_array = array();
$sub_array = array();
$index = $result[0]['question_text'];    

foreach($result as $value){

    $question_text = $value['question_text'];
    $answer_text = $value['answer_text'];
    $responses = $value['responses'];
    if (strcmp($index, $question_text) == 0) {
        $sub_array[$answer_text] = $responses;
    } else {
        $index = $question_text;
        $responses_array[$index] = $sub_array;
        $sub_array = array();
    }
}
```

Edit: Found my mistake, updated my answer slightly, hopefully this will work.

Edit 2: Working with example here: https://eval.in/687275

Comment: That gives me this:  

        [Have you made any changes in how you use our product this year?] => Array
        (
            [No] => 92
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Yes] => 30
                )

        ).   Sorry for the formatting. I don't know how to do it in a comment.

Comment: Only seems to capture the last question and has the wrong answers ~ https://eval.in/687271